# How do I properly reference Python classes?

Tags: python, class, module

I'm working on writing my first Python class. Being the java programmer that I am, I have something like this:

```
#class1.py
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
         #Do stuff here
```

And in my current script:

```
import class1
object = class1()
```

I'm getting a `Name Error: name 'class1' is not defined`

I've also tried this, with no luck:

```
import class1
object = class1.class1()
```

The error I get here is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'class1'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the actual name of the file / class? The second method *should* work.

Comment: `tle.py`/ `tle`. Not sure why it makes a difference...

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: No it shouldn't. The module name and class name are not required to be the same, nor are they the same thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the class is called class1 in a file named class1.py, it should work - this happened to be the case in the question. I was wondering whether the module name conflicted with something else.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Ah, I missed the second attempt.

Comment: This is an additional note. Since you are coming from Java to Python you may want to learn about good programming practices in Python. This [link](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) will tell you just about everything you need to know for good Python practices.

Comment: I'm with @ThomasOrozco; `class1.class1()` *should* work. (I wouldn't pick `object` as a name, though, as that would mask Python's built-in `object`.) The `AttributeError` is telling you that there isn't anything in the `class1` module (which imported successfully) named `class1`.

Comment: Hmm... to back up a bit, it's also mysterious that you got a `NameError` (it wouldn't have been `Name Error`; please just copy and paste error messages when you can, rather than retyping) when you tried `object = class1()`. What you *should have* gotten was `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python import is by module and then by the contents of the module, so for your class1.py it becomes:

```
from class1 import class1
```

[Python module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Wow, that simple... Thanks!

Comment: Well, this works, but it doesn't explain why `class1.class1()` can't be used as a constructor when the `class1` module has been successfully imported.

Comment: @JohnY That would have worked but it says in the comments under his question that his file name is tle.py. So they were importing the wrong module. Strange why there was no ImportError in that case though.

Comment: @StuartRobertson: No, the file name `tle.py` in the comments was just to confirm that the OP didn't *just happen* to pick a module name conflicting with something else. For purposes of the question, the module is the file `class1.py`, containing the class definition `class1`, as given in the text of the question. And ordinarily, you *should* be able to create an instance of `class1` by first importing the `class1` module, and then calling `class1.class1()`.

Answer (score -1):

In Python you import the modules. For class1.py file you can use:

```
from class1 import class1
```

Or if you have more than one....

```
from class1 import *
```